# ¿Como cambiar de color TEXT-VIEW y orientation:'vertical' y android:id="@+id/id"?

Tags: android-studio, xml

estoy con Android-Studio y necesito cambiar de forma dinámica unos parámetros en concreto desde el código. En xml equivalen a:

a) `android:textColor="#000"` (Cambiar el texto a negro)

b) `android:orientation="vertical"` (Layout con elementos descendentes)

c) `android:id="@+id/idDinamica"` (Para asignar a mis elementos una id en concreto)

Muchas grácias por vuestra ayuda, si he cometido algún error a la hora de preguntar y hacedmelo saber, que soy nuevo ;)

Comment: Puedes mostrar lo que has intentado hasta ahora.

Comment: Okey, en cuanto haga un avanze lo posteo :D

Comment: Sabes como enlazar una vista desde una actividad?

Comment: Así resumido tienes que crear una nueva Activity. Y luego para acceder a ella tu metes Intent i = new Intent(this, NuevaView.class );
        startActivity(i);

Comment: Mira este tutorial, lo explica bien: http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/javaya/androidya/androidstudioya/detalleconcepto.php?codigo=11&inicio=

Answer (score 0):

yo haría lo siguiente:

> a) android:textColor="**#000000**" (Cambiar el texto a negro)
>
> b) android:orientation="**horizontal**" (Layout con elementos descendentes)
>
> c) android:id="**@+id/tvnombre**" (Para asignar a mis elementos una id en concreto)

El código del textColor lo puedes sacar de aquí: 
https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp

La orientación, si fuera un LinearLayout creo que puedes jugar con "horizontal" y "vertical".

Respecto al id, suponiendo que tengas marcada el TextView de "Hello World" pues puedes ponerle una id concreta que sea "@+id/tvHello_World". Yo le pongo el tv delante para identificar que esa id corresponde a un elemento tipo texto visto.

Un saludo y espero responder tus dudas, 
Álvaro

Editado 04/02/2019

Comment: Creo que has entendido mal la pregunta, yo me refiero a que sea de forma dinámica, desde el propio codigo de android, no en xml. Tan solo has copiado y pegado mi ejemplo con otros parámetros. Grácias igualmente

Comment: "#ffffff" es blanco